# Null pointer exception in java when trying to load file

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm following the example here
http://www.bigerstaff.com/

I;ve added another class called Ball, and use an instance of it in this code

```
public class Ball extends Vector3 {

    public Sprite mSprite;
    public Texture mTexture;
```

So instead of using `blockTexture and blockSprite`,

```
blockTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/block.png"));
blockSprite = new Sprite(blockTexture);
```

I use

```
ball.mTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/block.png")); //error
ball.mSprite = new Sprite(ball.mTexture); //error
```

Sorry I am new to Java, but am I missing something very basic here?

Comment: could you please copy the full code ?

Comment: what line do you get the NPE on?

Comment: The stacktrace is of importance, shows the class and line number of the error, and calls

Comment: in the second line `blockTexture` is null. ball may be null as well in the first line already.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a `ball` object ? `ball` seems null.

Answer (score 0):

Switch

```
ball.mSprite = new Sprite(blockTexture);
```

for

```
ball.mSprite = new Sprite(ball.mTextture);
```

you are not creating the blockTexture object.

Comment: Well seen... took me longer to figure this out xD

Comment: sorry my mistake, I pasted some wrong code, please check the edit, this line I actually did how u said